# How to pass multiple dictionaries and access certain values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the following in Python:

```
dict1 = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 5,
}

dict2 = {
    'd': 2,
    'e': 3,
}

def do_sum(**dict1, **dict2):
    print(dict1['a'] + dict1['b'] + dict2['d'])

do_sum(**dict1, **dict2)
```

However, Python doesn't allow me to pass multiple `**kwargs` to a function. I tried doing this as well but an error:

```
def do_sum(dict1, dict2):
        print(dict1.values('a') + dict1.values('b') + dict2.values('d'))

    do_sum(dict1, dict2)
```

How can the operation in the function be achieved? Basically I want to pass multiple dictionaries but only want to access certain values in them.

Comment: It allows you to *pass* multiple kwargs, but it makes absolutely no sense to *receive* multiple kwargs; how is Python supposed to know which keys you want in which parameter? Also, if you're after specific arguments, you could do `def do_sum(a, b, d, **kwargs):` to pull out just the ones you need, and still call it `do_sum(**dict1, **dict2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the dictionary itself like this:

```py
dict1 = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 5,
}

dict2 = {
    'd': 2,
    'e': 3,
}

def do_sum(dict1, dict2):
    print(dict1['a'] + dict1['b'] + dict2['d'])

do_sum(dict1, dict2)
```

This is actually the exact same thing you wanted to do, ** just destructures the dictionary and then the function rebuilds it again. This is therefore also a bit faster.
if you really wanted to do your style, you could use dict.update() which merges 2 dictionaries. like this:

```py
import copy

dict1 = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 5,
}

dict2 = {
    'd': 2,
    'e': 3,
}


def do_sum(**dict3):
    print(dict3['a'] + dict3['b'] + dict3['d'])


dict3 = copy.copy(dict1)
dict3.update(dict2)

do_sum(**dict3)
```

Edit:
As jonrsharpe pointed out you do not need to build dict3. The code would look like this:

```py
dict1 = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 3,
    'c': 5,
}

dict2 = {
    'd': 2,
    'e': 3,
}


def do_sum(**dict3):
    print(dict3['a'] + dict3['b'] + dict3['d'])


do_sum(**dict1, **dict2)
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to build `dict3`, Python *does* allow multiple dictionaries to be unpacked to one function when calling it ([from 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)).

Comment: You are completely right. Silly of me not thinking of that. I will add a third section to do it in your way.